# get-aduser and exclude specfic name

Tags: powershell

i want to get some user from ad and their properties but i want exclude some users starting with "health*"
that's what i have but it doesn't filter these users out. maybe someone can help

```
[array] $ADExcludedUser = 'Health*'
$DaysInactive = 180  
$Time = (Get-Date).Adddays( - ($DaysInactive))

$AllUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter { LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $Time -and enabled -eq $true } -Properties * |  Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate | Sort-Object name 
$AllUsersExceptExcluded = $AllUsers | where-object { $_.name -notin $ADExcludedUser } | Out-GridView
```

Comment: where-object { $_.name -notmatch $ADExcludedUser }

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`Get-ADUser | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike "Health*" }`

Answer (score 0):

You can put that right in the filter:

```
get-aduser -filter 'name -notlike "health*"'
```